# When applying semidefinite optimization to sum of squares polynomials, why do you want the determinant of you polynomial matrix to be non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, determinant, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

We're studying semidefinite optimization in order to see if a polynomial can be written as a sum of squares. So to put it in a more math-appropriate form,
 for $p\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, we want to rewrite it of the form $p=\sum q_i^2 $ where $q_i\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, now we can rewrite $p = (x^2, xy, y^2)Q(x^2, xy, y^2)^T$ and if $Q$ is positive semidefinite, it can be written as $p = (x^2, xy, y^2)Q(x^2, xy, y^2)^T = (x^2, xy, y^2)LL^T(x^2, xy, y^2)^T = (x^2, xy, y^2)L(L(x^2, xy, y^2))^T$
which is a sum of squares.

Now, our lecturer said we would need to assure our diagonal elements are non-negative and (and this is where I've lost it) $det(Q)\geq 0$ in order for $Q$ to be PSD because then the eigenvalues are non-negative. But because $Q\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$, we cant assume our matrix is PSD in that case because we could still have 2 negative eigenvalues and 1 non-negative.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct: having nonnegative determinant and nonnegative diagonal elements is not enough to ensure that a $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix is psd.
For example,

$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$

You'll also want to require that the three $2 \times 2$ principal minors are nonnegative.

Comment: Nice! I can work with that. But just to make sure, for a $3\times3$ problem this is do-able, but for much larger problems this is not really a feasible approach as there are too many principal minors to take into account?

Comment: Answer to Britta: You do not work with the minors when you solve sum-of-squares problems using semidefinite programming. The problem is solved numerically over the cone of positive semidefinite matrices.